# Spark context is created every time a batch job is executed in yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I am wondering, is there any way where i create the spark-context once in the YARN cluster, then the incoming jobs will re-use that context. The context creation takes 20s or sometimes more in my cluster. I am using pyspark for scripting and livy to submit jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't just have a standing SparkContext running in Yarn.  Maybe another idea is to run in client mode, where the client has it's own SparkContext (this is the method used by tools like Apache Zeppelin and the spark-shell).

Comment: Hmmm. What if there is some mechanism to add remotely created driver on server, while submitting job. ?

Comment: Yes it should be possible to create an application that takes queries and interprets them.  The Spark thrift-server works that way.  The problem is you're then building a full application to deal with what you're looking to do.  Client mode is just easier.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use [Apache Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/). Livy is an additional server in your Yarn cluster that provides an interface for clients that want to run Spark jobs on the cluster. One of Livy's features is that you can

> Have long running Spark Contexts that can be used for multiple Spark jobs, by multiple clients

If the client is written in Scala or Java it is possible to use a [programmatic API](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/programmatic-api.html):

```java
LivyClient client = new LivyClientBuilder()....build();
Object result = client.submit(new SparkJob(sparkParameters)).get();
```

All other clients can use a [REST API](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html).